# Aggregate / designated initialization of c++ struct: Refer directly to another field

Tags: c++, c++20, aggregate-initialization, designated-initializer

When using aggregate / designated initialization of a struct it is possible to refer to another field like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  struct
  {
    int a;
    int b;
  }
  s = 
  {
    .a = 3,
    .b = s.a + 1,
  };

  return 0;
}
```

We use s.a in the initialization of s.b. However, we need to refer to s.a through s. Is it possible to refer directly to s.a as just `.a`, or similar? This would for instance make it possible to use the same syntax when initializing arrays of structs like here:

```
int main()
{
  struct
  {
    int a;
    int b;
  }
  s[] = 
  {
    {
      .a = 3,
      .b = s[0].a + 1,
    },
    {
      .a = 5,
      .b = s[1].a - 1,
    }
  };

  return 0;
}
```

Here we could maybe write something like `.b = .a - 1` instead of `.b = s[1].a - 1`.

Comment: Even if you could refer directly to a member in the initializing expression, how would that help in the array case? Given `.b = .a - 1` how would you distinguish between `.b = s[0].a - 1` and `.b = s[1].a - 1`?

Comment: @cigien They would be distinguished through the scope, like if `.a` was a normal variable.

Comment: Ok, let's say that worked, would `.a` refer to `s[0].a` or `s[1].a`? Both are in the same scope.

Comment: @cigien If the brace initialiers for each struct were treated as a scope, then they would be in different scopes. Of course this is probably a  theoretical discussion since it doesn't seem to work like that.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work like that, but there's nothing wrong with theory :) I see now what you want the code to do, I misunderstood that. And yes, that's a reasonable thing to expect the code to do, except for the rules not allowing it :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to refer directly to `s.a` as just `.a`, or similar?

No, `.a` in this context is a *designator*, and it cannot be referred to in the *brace-or-equal-initializer* used to initialize a given data member by means of its matching designator.

```
struct Bar { int a; };

struct Foo {
    int a;
    Bar b;
};

int main() {
    Foo f = {
     //     ^ start of braced-init-list
        .a
     // ^^ designator (for data member of Foo)
            = 1,
     //     ^^^ initializer-clause
        .b{.a = 2}
     //   ^^^^^^^^ braced-init-list
     //   referring to a designator of a 
     //   data member of Bar
    };
}
```

#### Details

Designated initializers, a new C++20 feature introduced by [P0329R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0329r4.pdf), are part of [the grammar for *braced-init-lists*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#nt:braced-init-list):

> ```
> braced-init-list:
>   { initializer-list ,opt }
>   { designated-initializer-list ,opt }
>   { }
> ```

where [the grammar of *designated-initializer-list*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#nt:designated-initializer-list) is:

> ```
> designated-initializer-list:
>   designated-initializer-clause
>   designated-initializer-list , designated-initializer-clause
> ```

and, where the grammar for the individual [*designated-initializer-clause*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#nt:designated-initializer-clause):s is:

> ```
> designated-initializer-clause:
>   designator brace-or-equal-initializer
> ```

and where finally, [a *designator*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#nt:designator) is:

> ```
> designator:
>   . identifier
> ```

Now, a [*brace-or-equal-initializer*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#nt:brace-or-equal-initializer) does not allow, in any way, to refer to *another* designator of the same object. Note here the difference here between designators and *other* identifiers, e.g. referring to data members of the struct as part of the *initializer-clause* or nested *braced-init-list*:s of the *brace-or-equal-initializer*.